# Unselecting columns in DT::formatRound in Shiny when the columns change position due to user selection

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I am making a shiny app (https://joshmyers.shinyapps.io/WAINorms/). The third tab, "Normative Data", displays a datatable based on a couple of user inputs. My output code for the table is:

```
output$table = renderDataTable({
datatable(norms.df(), options = list(
lengthMenu = list(c(50, 100, 200, -1), c('50', '100', '200', 'All')), 
pageLength = 100), rownames = FALSE, class = 'white-space: nowrap stripe hover') 
%>% formatRound(columns = -c(1:2), digits =  2)
})
```

The `formatRound` function rounds all of the columns except the first two to 2 decimal places. The problem is that this also rounds the "Percentile" column, which I don't want.

The issue is that it switches places depending on the selection of "Ethnic Specific" - if "No" Percentile is the 3rd column, but if "Yes" it becomes the 4th column, as another column, "Ethnicity", is inserted.

How can I round all columns to 2 decimal places except for "Measure", "Age", "Percentile", and "Ethnicity"?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't exactly what I wanted, but I can live with it. You can chain `formatRound` functions together (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) so I could have rounded the 'Percentile' column to one decimal place which would have been acceptable. I decided to use `formatSignif` instead, however.

```
datatable(norms.df()) %>% 
formatSignif("Percentile", 3) %>% 
formatRound( -c(1:2), 2)
```